# Openlayers is not showing markers

Tags: views, javascript, location

I'm using openlayers module with geofield. The markers are showing fine on the views preview and all looks good. but when viewing the display page through it's path the markers don't show. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Use firebug or something similar to check if there are any javascript errors on page load. Maybe a javascript error is causing the point not to load?

Comment: What version of openlayers and geofield are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll add my suggeston here. I had a similar problem. The thing is - if your field is a polygon, polygons won't appear as markers on the map. To solve this, in Views, under the settings for your location field in the data overlay, instead of full geometry, choose "use centroid".